# swing tableChanged() not responding to table changes

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

I'm coding in Swing in Java. I'm using the Netbeans layout manager. I'm having trouble with a jTable. I've applied a customer model to it which extends AbstractTableModel. I want the third column to contain boolean values in the form of checkboxes (this I have done successfully). The dialog I have the jTable in implements TableModelListener. My tableChanged() method has only the following code: `System.out.println("Table changed!");`
However, whenever I try to check one of the checkboxes, it does the little "suppression" thing when I click and hold, then when I release, it doesn't change the checkbox's state. It also does not print out "The table has changed!" This has been driving me crazy. I've read all about it, but can't figure out why mine's not working. Please help. Here's the relevant code:

In jDialog constructor:

```
this.chapterTableModel = new ChapterTableModel(chapterList);
chapterTableModel.addTableModelListener(this);
```

And then a method which does this: `chapterTable.setModel(chapterTableModel);`

Then below my constructor, I have this method:

```
@Override
public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent tme) {
  System.out.println("Table Changed!");
}
```

The entire code can be found here: http://collabedit.com/ttcds
and here: http://collabedit.com/qn3kx

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem. And start with the DefaultTableModel not your custom TableModel to help narrow down the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm not exactly sure what to do to better implement SSCCE standards. I'm working on switching over to the DefaultTableModel. It's firing the tableChanged() method now, but now I'm having difficulty making the third column be boolean checkboxes instead of strings with "false" or "true"

Comment: To display checkboxes you override the getColumnClass() method of the JTable or the DefaultTableModel to return Boolean.class for the column and the table will choose the appropriate renderer and editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not overriding [setValueAt](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#setValueAt%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) anywhere so the value in your table isn't being changed.

Comment: But should that prevent it from even printing out "Table changed!"?

Comment: Sweet! That worked! I guess it makes sense. I still don't understand why the tableChanged() doesn't go when I click them, but it's working now. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @kentd Yeah, the values in the table are never changed so the listener is never fired. Override the setValueAt and have it update the ignored flag and fire a table changed event.

Comment: thanks. Weird thing, the checkbox updates without calling the fireTable method. Is there a reason for that? Should I make a fireTable method to make sure or is it good as is?

Comment: @kentd No problem. Adding a call to one of the fireTableBlahChanged method should make the tableChanged call fire.

Answer (score 3):

Are you calling one of the fire-methods of the parent AbstractTableModel class in the mutators of ChapterTableModel?

Comment: Yes, in the ChapterTableModel:
`public void fireTable() {`
  `this.fireTableDataChanged();`
`}`

Comment: If your updating the table model via editable cells you have to override the setValueAt-method, where you update your data and then call fireTableCellUpdated: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Comment: Thanks a ton! That's what it was. So the tableChanged() method isn't necessary? Does that mean I don't need to implement TableModelListener in my jDialog holding the jTable? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: If other parts of your UI would like to be notified if the table changed, you can register a listener. E.g. to enable a Save-button.